# How to replace html tag in ruby without using Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to replace a `<blockquote>` tag with text in an HTMl document. I started off using Nokogiri to do this. The problem is the HTML I pass to Nokogiri contains text like `<my_mail@gmail.com>` which nokogiri considers as a tag. The output is all screwed because Nokogiri tries to correct the "tag" by adding `</my_mail>` to the html doc.

Any ideas how to turn off this auto correction in Nokogiri or are there any other gems I can use to do this without screwing the output?

Comment: That is invalid HTML. The brackets should be escaped.

Comment: Nokogiri is doing the right thing, and the HTML is broken. @lisukorin's suggestion is the right way to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape `<` and `>` around mail before sending string to Nokogiri.

```
>> "<html><body><my_mail@gmail.com></body></html>".gsub(/<([^<]+@[^>]+)>/,'&lt;\1&gt;')
=> "<html><body>&lt;my_mail@gmail.com&gt;</body></html>"
```

Comment: This is my recommended way to fix the problem. Pathologically broken HTML occurs, and when it does it has to be tweaked to allow Nokogiri to figure it out. Been there, done it, many times.